# releasing desktop application that created by using flutter

Tags: flutter, desktop-application, flutter-desktop

today I tried desktop app development using flutter, but once I use 'flutter build windows' command in terminal it says:
"Warning: Only debug is currently implemented for Windows. This is effectively a debug build."
"See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38477 for details and updates."

I wonder to know if I can build and release desktop applications or its still not supported.

Comment: Desktop release is working now

Comment: how ? is there any tutorials ?

Comment: no man still there are  so many changes is remaining in flutter web and desktop.

Comment: so I cannot release my created desktop app, right ?

Comment: exactly i don't know about it, when i was tried to do desktop release then i face this issue.

Comment: I hope someone here can help us both

Answer (score 2):

It is still not supported.

The tool is explicitly telling you that you can't make a non-debug Windows build, and it links to the bug in the Flutter repository for release build support, which is still open; you're not going to be able to find a more authoritative answer than that.

Also, if you are building for Windows then you presumably got your runner from the [flutter-desktop-embedding project](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding), which says:

> **The code here is not stable, nor intended for production use.**